# How to "AND" search keywords on the Foursquare API?

Tags: api, foursquare

Searching the foursquare api by lat/lng with a keyword that contains multiple words like "furniture store" appears to search on an "OR" basis like "furniture OR store", but I'd prefer on an "AND" basis like "furniture AND store".

The results from the OR search many times don't make sense. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Foursquare venues search doesn't support keywords like AND or OR. Based on your examples, though, you might be best off using a category restrict. See the "categoryId" param on [/venues/search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search)